# Replace month number with month name using current phone format

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm using joda-time to process DateTime. I got date format of phone using this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String datePattern = dateFormat.toPattern();
```

And then I format a DateTime to String using this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
dateFormatter.print(dateTime)
```

Example, it will show DateTime as String:

> 3/1/2016

But i want it displays:

> March/1/2016

or

> Mar/1/2016

How can i do that?

Comment: If you want a specific format, use that. But just replacing month number with month name could be *really* weird in some formats. Sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, maybe i will think about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method

```
public static String getDateFormattedString(String sourceFormat,String dateString,String targetFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat mOriginalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormat);//3/1/2016
    SimpleDateFormat mTargetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(targetFormat);//Mar/1/2016

    String reqstring = null;
    try {
        reqstring = mTargetFormat.format(mOriginalFormat.parse(dateString));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reqstring;
}
```

and then call

```
String resultantDate=getDateFormattedString("MM/dd/yyyy", "3/1/2016", "MMM/d/yyyy");
```

Use target format: `MMM/d/yyyy  for Mar/1/2016` and `MMMMM/d/yyyy forar March/1/2016`

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP is trying to get the "MMM/d/yyyy" pattern - there's no indication that they need to parse and reformat...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Following code helps. String mFormat=datePattern.substring(datePattern.indexOf('M'), datePattern.lastIndexOf('M')+1);
      datePattern=datePattern.replace(mFormat, "MMM");// "MMMM"
      DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
      dateFormatter.print(dateTime)

Comment: Your code sample still parses and reformats for no obvious reason though. I suggest you edit the answer - it's still not what I'd look for, to be honest... I fundamentally don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the pattern to achieve the desired effect. Proposal:

```
java.util.Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String pattern = dateFormat.toPattern();

DateTime joda = new DateTime(d); // in default timezone
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("old format: " + fmt.print(joda));

// does not handle the case where the month appears twice or more in pattern (simplification)
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
    if (pattern.charAt(i) == 'M') {
        count++;
    }
}

// your first configuration parameter
boolean wantsAbbreviation = false;

// your second configuration parameter - consider Locale.getDefault()
Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH; 

String replacement = (wantsAbbreviation ? "MMM" : "MMMM");

if (count == 2) {
    pattern = pattern.replace("MM", replacement);
} else if (count == 1) {
    pattern = pattern.replace("M", replacement);
} else {
    // either no month or already text format
}

DateTimeFormatter fmtNew = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withLocale(locale);
System.out.println("new format: " + fmtNew.print(joda));

// old format: 03/03/2016
// new format: March/03/2016
```

However, I don't give any guarantee that the cell phone format always uses pattern letters which are understood by Joda-Time because `SimpleDateFormat` and Joda-Time format pattern definitions are not identical. But at least for month pattern symbol "M", it should work. Eventually you have also to check the letter "L" (month in standalone format, relevant for many slavish languages), but that letter is not understood by Joda-Time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date_1 = sdf1.parse("2016-03-08");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf2.format(date_1));
```

Comment: This ignores the "using current phone format" part of the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Check the edited answer because this time current phone format is being used

Comment: No it's not. You've still hard-coded the format... It won't vary based on user locale.